# C++ to Delphi pointer conversion

Tags: c++, delphi, pointers

I am trying to convert an open source C++ project to Delphi(Berlin 10.1). it uses some pointers which i can not find a way to convert them to Delphi pointers. How can i translate this piece code from C++ to Delphi?
Here is the code:

```
int SolveAll(int DragFunction, double DragCoefficient, double Vi, 
      double SightHeight, 
      double ShootingAngle, double ZAngle, double WindSpeed, double WindAngle, 
      double** Solution)
{    
    double* ptr;

    ptr = (double*)malloc(10*__BCOMP_MAXRANGE__*sizeof(double)+2048);

    double t=0;
    double dt=0.5/Vi;
    double v=0;
    double vx=0, vx1=0, vy=0, vy1=0;
    double dv=0, dvx=0, dvy=0;
    double x=0, y=0;

    double headwind=HeadWind(WindSpeed, WindAngle);
    double crosswind=CrossWind(WindSpeed, WindAngle);

    double Gy=GRAVITY*cos(DegtoRad((ShootingAngle + ZAngle)));
    double Gx=GRAVITY*sin(DegtoRad((ShootingAngle + ZAngle)));

    vx=Vi*cos(DegtoRad(ZAngle));
    vy=Vi*sin(DegtoRad(ZAngle));

    y=-SightHeight/12;

    int n=0;
    for (t=0;;t=t+dt){

        vx1=vx, vy1=vy; 
        v=pow(pow(vx,2)+pow(vy,2),0.5);
        dt=0.5/v;


        dv = retard(DragFunction,DragCoefficient,v+headwind);       
        dvx = -(vx/v)*dv;
        dvy = -(vy/v)*dv;


        vx=vx + dt*dvx + dt*Gx;
        vy=vy + dt*dvy + dt*Gy;



        if (x/3>=n){
            ptr[10*n+0]=x/3;                            
            ptr[10*n+1]=y*12;                           
            ptr[10*n+2]=-RadtoMOA(atan(y/x));           
            ptr[10*n+3]=t+dt;                           
            ptr[10*n+4]=Windage(crosswind,Vi,x,t+dt);   
            ptr[10*n+5]=RadtoMOA(atan(ptr[10*n+4]));    
            ptr[10*n+6]=v;                              
            ptr[10*n+7]=vx;                         
            ptr[10*n+8]=vy;                     
            ptr[10*n+9]=0;                              
            n++;    
        }   

        // Compute position based on average velocity.
        x=x+dt*(vx+vx1)/2;
        y=y+dt*(vy+vy1)/2;

        if (fabs(vy)>fabs(3*vx)) break;
        if (n>=__BCOMP_MAXRANGE__+1) break;
    }

    ptr[10*__BCOMP_MAXRANGE__+1]=(double)n;

    *Solution = ptr;

    return n;
}
```

Comment: There is probably a solution not involving pointer trickery. We need to see the calling site and know what you are allowed to change about the interface.

Comment: I didn't read all of the function body, but I guess you're better off using an Delphi dynamic array (`TDoubleArray  = array of Double;` without bounds). If `n` is the final length of the array you can even return the array instead. If not pass the array as `var`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
type
   TDoubleArray  = array[Word] of Double;
   PDoubleArray  = ^TDoubleArray;


ptr: PDoubleArray;

GetMem(ptr, 10*sizeof(double)+324);


ptr[10*n+1] := y*12;   

ptr[1] := n;
```

Edit after full code adding:

```
argument definition:  
    ... var Solution: PDoubleArray)
in this case usage:   
    Solution := ptr;
```

Comment: The last part is wrong. That's really just a var param of type `double*`. And static arrays are kind of lame here. POINTERMATH ON gets the job done much better.  I personally have little patience with spoon feeding. Why can't we stand our ground and demand proper questions? So we can help the asker to learn.

Comment: "double** Solution" should be like 2*2 array as i understand ?

Comment: No. `double**` is a pointer to a linear array, in this particular case. Because you only showed very little code, with no context, I'm having to guess that, but I think it's reasonably clear from the code we have.

Comment: thanks. I add the full code above.

Comment: @David Last part wasn't wrong (but ugly). There were no information that Solution is function argument.

Comment: It was clear to me and the edit confirms my hunch. It's still really horrible with the static array.

Answer (score 0):

```
type
 DoubleArray = Array[Word] of Double;
 PDoubleArray = ^DoubleArray;

const
 __BCOMP_MAXRANGE__ = 5; // for Example

var
 Ptr : ^DoubleArray;
 Solution : ^PDoubleArray;
 Y : Double;
 N : Integer;
begin
 Ptr := AllocMem(10*SizeOf(Double)+324); // Initialize with Zero
 // OR
 GetMem(Ptr, 10*SizeOf(Double)+324); // Without Initializing
 ...
 Ptr^[10*N+1] := Y*12;
 ...
 Ptr^[10*__BCOMP_MAXRANGE__ + 1] := N;
 ...
 Solution := @Ptr;

 ShowMessage(FloatToStr(Solution^^[1])); // Example for using 'Solution'
 ...

 // Free Memory using FreeMem(Ptr) at the End
end;
```